# Windows 10 python.exe neither runs nor gives error in command line

Tags: python, cmd

When I try to run the `python.exe` in my windows command prompt, or in the VSCode Terminal, the python script shows no signs of running. It isn't showing any error.

This is a picture of what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the program was not showing an error, was that it actually found a `python.exe` on the machine under a *WindowsApps* folder. This program opened the windows store. Once python was installed onto the computer, the program worked.

Comment: One way to test if this is the issue is by typing `python.exe --version`. The _real_ Python will show a version number. The _Windows Store_ Python will not show a version number.